# Python request.head(): How to get response code using python request module instead of Exception

Tags: python, url, request

It returns the 200, 301 and some other responses as expected. But when i try to get responses of some non existent website, instead of returning codes, it throws exception. Below is the code when i tried to get response code for "www.googl.com", I'm expecting a response code for this scenario.Even i can handle it in `try` and `except` but actually i need response code.

Code:

```
import requests

print (requests.head("https://www.googl.com"))
```

Comment: Response codes are set by a server not client application. If `requests` is unable to connect to a server it raises an exception. What code do you expect from a server that does not exist?

Comment: How should a non existing server send you a **response** code?

Comment: Thanks! Incase, if "www.googl.com" is exist and down for the moment, what response code will it throw? I just want to differentiate both the scenarios with response code! Is it possible?

Comment: It won't throw anything, unless they have a fallback or run through a service like cloudflare; in which case it depends. But you'll usually find something like `500` or `504` or `404`

Comment: okay..I got the context. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nothing is being returned, there is no response code, because there was no response.

Your best bet is just doing this:

```
import requests
try:
    response = requests.head("https://www.googl.com")
except:
    response = 404 # or whatever you want.
```

Comment: No problem, if the issue is resolved mark an answer as the correct answer so people know not to try and answer again and people can find it :) Which you can do with the big tick underneath the voting on an answer.